# How to show/hide the progressHUD, with MVVM and RxSwift in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift, svprogresshud

I'm beginning with MVVM in order to well separate logic code from the view. But I have some concern about where to put the progressHUD related code when tapping a button that makes a request.

Before, I used to do that:

```
//Before 
@IBAction func startRequestTapped() {
   SVProgressHUD.show()
    self.apiClient.requestObservable().subscribe(onError: { (error) in
        SVProgressHUD.hide()                    
    }, onCompleted: { 
        SVProgressHUD.hide()                                        
    })
}
```

But when I use mvvm, I do like that:

```
//In the viewModel
public var validateButtonDidTap = PublishSubject<Void>()
init() {
    validateButtonDidTap.flatMap { (_)
        return self.apiClient.requestObservable()
    }
}


   // In the viewController
viewDidLoad() {
    let tap = self.validateButton.rx.tap
    tap.bindTo(self.viewModel.validateButtonDidTap)
}
```

And amongst that, I don't know where to put the the ProgressHUD hide or show.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mark answer is right, but I am going to guide you step by step.

Let's supose you're going to try signing in.

1. Copy [ActivityIndicator.swift file](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftUtilities/blob/master/Source/ActivityIndicator.swift) in your project.
2. In the `viewModel`:

   ```
   //MARK: - Properties

   /// The http client
   private let apiClient: YourApiClient

   /// Clousure when button is tapped
   var didTappedButton: () -> Void = {}

   /// The user 
   var user: Observable<User>

   /// Is signing process in progress
   let signingIn: Observable<Bool> = ActivityIndicator().asObservable()

   //MARK: - Initialization

   init(client: YourApiClient) {
       self.client = client

       self.didTappedButton = { [weak self] in
           self.user = self.apiClient
                           .yourSignInRequest()
                           .trackActivity(self.signingIn)
                           .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create an extension of SVProgressHUD: (I don't know SVProgressHUD library, but it would be something like this. Please fix it if needed)

   ```
   extension Reactive where Base: SVProgressHUD {

       /// Bindable sink for `show()`, `hide()` methods.
       public static var isAnimating: UIBindingObserver<Base, Bool> {
           return UIBindingObserver(UIElement: self.base) { progressHUD, isVisible in
               if isVisible {
                   progressHUD.show() // or other show methods
               } else {
                   progressHUD.dismiss() // or other hide methods
               }
           }
       }

   }
   ```
4. In your `viewController`:

   ```
   @IBAction func startRequestTapped() {
       viewModel.didTappedButton()
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {

       // ...

       viewModel.signingIn
                .bindTo(SVProgressHUD.rx.isAnimating)
                .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about adding reactive extension to an existing class

Comment: @Xfreire can you explain whats the where in extension means?

Comment: @XFreire: I am getting error - Cannot convert value of type 'Observable<Bool>' to expected argument type 'ActivityIndicator' on .trackActivity(self.signingIn) line

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answer updated to Swift 4, RxSwift 4.0.0 and SVProgressHUD 2.2.2:

3- Extension:

```
extension Reactive where Base: SVProgressHUD {

   public static var isAnimating: Binder<Bool> {
      return Binder(UIApplication.shared) {progressHUD, isVisible in
         if isVisible {
            SVProgressHUD.show()
         } else {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
         }
      }
   }

}
```

4- Controller:

```
viewModel.signingIn.asObservable().bind(to: SVProgressHUD.rx.isAnimating).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try using an `ActivityIndicator`.

See the example here:
https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftUtilities